# Extract number before string using regex

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

Given:

```
s = '2X-Large/3X-Large (4 Count)'
```

Can someone suggest how to extract 4 from s using regex in Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `re.findall` here:

```
s = "2X-Large/3X-Large (4 Count)"
counts = re.findall(r'\((\d+) Count\)', s)
print(counts)
```

This prints:

```
['4']
```